# Python urllib function reading wrong page

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I'm using python 2.7 (in Windows 7 OS) I'm just trying to read a webpage using urllib function and writing it to a file. Below is my code.

```
import urllib

html=urllib.urlopen("http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S027252311730076X").readlines()

print len(html)

g=open("D:\path\to\output\output.html",'w')

for i in html:

    g.write(i)
g.close()
```

But when I compared the page source of the above mentioned link in browser (by right click -> View page source) and my output html file they are different. Many information are missing in my output.html file. Why is that? and how can i get the original page source? Because I have to further write few more codes to extract some specific info from this page.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you open the link in your browser, you see there is one more link to click to go to the current link

Comment: `http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S027252311730076X?via=sd` is this the page you want to get content from?

Comment: But that link is redirecting to the same page. I used this link (http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S027252311730076‌​X?via=sd) in urllib.urlopen as well, But I'm getting error like "Unsupported characters in input"